# C# version of OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey method?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, openssl, md5

I'm looking for straight-up .NET implementation of the OpenSSL [EVP_BytesToKey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) function. The closest thing I've found is the [System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) class (and [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7092977/2047))  but it seems to be [slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855526/equivalent-to-passwordderivebytes-in-openssl) and doesn't generate the same **key** and **iv** as EVP_BytesToKey.

I also found this [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452422/openssl-using-only-net-classes/5454692#5454692) which seems like a good start but doesn't take into account iteration count.

I realize there's OpenSSL.NET but it's just a wrapper around the native openssl DLLs not a "real" .NET implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this pseudo-code explanation of the **EVP_BytesToKey** method (in [/doc/ssleay.txt](http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/doc/ssleay.txt&v=1.5.4.2) of the openssl source):

```
/* M[] is an array of message digests
 * MD() is the message digest function */
M[0]=MD(data . salt);
for (i=1; i<count; i++) M[0]=MD(M[0]);

i=1
while (data still needed for key and iv)
    {
    M[i]=MD(M[i-1] . data . salt);
    for (i=1; i<count; i++) M[i]=MD(M[i]);
    i++;
    }

If the salt is NULL, it is not used.
The digests are concatenated together.
M = M[0] . M[1] . M[2] .......
```

So based on that I was able to come up with this C# method (which seems to work for my purposes and assumes 32-byte key and 16-byte iv):

```
private static void DeriveKeyAndIV(byte[] data, byte[] salt, int count, out byte[] key, out byte[] iv)
{
    List<byte> hashList = new List<byte>();
    byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];

    int preHashLength = data.Length + ((salt != null) ? salt.Length : 0);
    byte[] preHash = new byte[preHashLength];

    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, preHash, 0, data.Length);
    if (salt != null)
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, preHash, data.Length, salt.Length);

    MD5 hash = MD5.Create();
    currentHash = hash.ComputeHash(preHash);          

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        currentHash = hash.ComputeHash(currentHash);            
    }

    hashList.AddRange(currentHash);

    while (hashList.Count < 48) // for 32-byte key and 16-byte iv
    {
        preHashLength = currentHash.Length + data.Length + ((salt != null) ? salt.Length : 0);
        preHash = new byte[preHashLength];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(currentHash, 0, preHash, 0, currentHash.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length, data.Length);
        if (salt != null)
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length + data.Length, salt.Length);

        currentHash = hash.ComputeHash(preHash);            

        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            currentHash = hash.ComputeHash(currentHash);
        }

        hashList.AddRange(currentHash);
    }
    hash.Clear();
    key = new byte[32];
    iv = new byte[16];
    hashList.CopyTo(0, key, 0, 32);
    hashList.CopyTo(32, iv, 0, 16);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Here's more/less the same implementation but uses the .NET DeriveBytes interface: https://gist.github.com/1339719

---

[OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.

Comment: Thank you! Also to keep in mind, the default run of OpenSSL uses `iterations=1`.