# Using Python PyCrypto with Perl Crypt::CBC

Tags: python, perl, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

On one side I have a texts encrypted/decrypted with Perl's [`Crypt::CBC`](http://metacpan.org/module/Crypt::CBC)

```
my $key = 'key to the gates'; 
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key    => $key,
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -salt   => '12341234'  
);
```

On the other side I have Python's [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) that I need to decode the data from Perl, but also send text that the Perl cipher can read given the encryption.

I have the key from the Perl program, and encrypt_hex:ed passphrases from Perl sent to the Python system.

But Python seems to absolutely want to have the IV to do its job

```
cipher = Blowfish.new( self.key, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, self.iv )
        return hexlify(cipher.encrypt(raw))
```

However, the `Crypt::CBC` documnetation seems to indicate that the IV is there already

> "salt" -- Combine the passphrase with an 8-byte random value to
>             generate both the block cipher key and the IV from the
>             provided passphrase. The salt will be appended to the
>             beginning of the data stream allowing decryption to
>             regenerate both the key and IV given the correct
>             passphrase.

Is there any way to extract the IV from the key/passphrase via PyCrypto? Or does IV have to be sent separately in some way?

This might be a naive question but I don't work with this every day.

I know I can get the IV from the Perl side, but I really want to extract it on Python side if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't like my edit, but remember that the primary purpose of your question and any solutions you may be offered is to help other people with a similar problem, which means the subject line should help to guide those people towards this page.

Comment: Oops! I am new here and did not know other persons could edit your posts, so i thought i had done something and tried to rollback. Now that i know, you are most welcome to re-edit if you like ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Crypt::CBC` claims OpenSSL compatibility. This means that it performs an OpenSSL specific `BytesToKey` password-based key derivation function (PBKDF). During this derivation the IV is calculated as well. So the key you've provided for `Crypt::CBC` is actually treated as a password.

You have to lookup an implementation of [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) and integrate that into your program. You can start with this code [from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/gsakkis/4546068):

```
def bytes_to_key(data, salt="12345678"):
    # Simplified version of M2Crypto.m2.bytes_to_key(). Based on:
    # https://github.com/ajmirsky/M2Crypto/blob/master/M2Crypto/EVP.py#L105
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008253/c-sharp-version-of-openssl-evp-bytestokey-method
    assert len(salt) == 8, len(salt)
    data += salt
    key = md5(data).digest()
    key += md5(key + data).digest()
    return key
```

Then take the first bytes for the key, and the next 8 bytes for the IV. But note the following statement for Crypt:CBC:

> If -keysize is not specified, then Crypt::CBC will use the maximum length Blowfish key size of 56 bytes (448 bits).

So you may need a few more `key += md5(key + data).digest()` calls as the md5 output is only 128 bits.