# CryptoJS unpad issue

Tags: python, cryptojs

I am decrypting the encoded data fetched from API using **CryptoJS** **data is coming from node js crypto-js in a string format**.

Here is what I have tried

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad,unpad

make = make.json()['data']
key = "SecretPassphrase"
encrypted_make = self.decrypt(make,key)

def decrypt(self,encrypted, passphrase):
    encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted)
    IV = encrypted[:16]
    aes = AES.new(passphrase.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_CFB, IV, segment_size=128)
    return unpad(aes.decrypt(encrypted[16:]),aes.block_size)
```

I am getting the issue `{ValueError}Padding is incorrect.` Can I know what I am trying wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a sample data set for which you get this error?

Comment: @Jib it's length is 29400 I can not paste it here I guess

Comment: Indeed .. where do you get the ciphered data from? Do you cipher it yourself or is it provided as is?

Comment: @Jib I hit the API from my other Node JS project it encrypts the data and returns me the encrypted string.

Comment: Is 29400 the length of the received payload, or the length of the data after being base64 decoded?

Comment: @Jib No the data received in the payload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249591/discussion-between-syed-arsalan-hussain-and-jib).

Comment: Send the encrypted string from your other NodeJS project as an attachment to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion from the chat, we found out that the issue was not related to padding. Actually it is related to the decryption key.

The CryptoJS API considers the provided key as a pass phrase, not as a key. Thus, it processes it to create a key from it. When using that passphrase as the decryption key on the Python side, it results in inconsistent decoded data because the decryption key does not match the encryption key generated from the given pass phrase on the CryptoJS side.

According to the CryptoJS documentation, we have three points:

- the default AES operating mode is CBC, not CFB.
- the pass phrase is hashed using the MD5 algorithm to produce a key.
- the generated encrypted message starts with `b"Salted__"` before the 8bytes IV.

In order to convert the CryptoJS pass phrase to a key, the following piece of code helps (taken from [Github](https://gist.github.com/gsakkis/4546068#file-aes-py-L49)):

```
def bytes_to_key(data, salt="12345678"):
    # Simplified version of M2Crypto.m2.bytes_to_key(). Based on:
    # https://github.com/ajmirsky/M2Crypto/blob/master/M2Crypto/EVP.py#L105
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008253/c-sharp-version-of-openssl-evp-bytestokey-method
    assert len(salt) == 8, len(salt)
    data += salt
    key = md5(data).digest()
    key += md5(key + data).digest()
    return key
```

Then the decryption logic mainly remains the same and goes like:

```
def bytes_to_key(data, salt, output=48):
    assert len(salt) == 8, len(salt)
    data += salt
    key = md5(data).digest()
    final_key = key
    while len(final_key) < output:
        key = md5(key + data).digest()
        final_key += key
    return final_key[:output]

def decrypt(encrypted, passphrase):
    assert encrypted[0:8] == b"Salted__"
    salt = encrypted[8:16]
    key_iv = bytes_to_key(passphrase, salt, 32 + 16)
    iv = key_iv[32:]
    key = key_iv[:32]
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(aes.decrypt(encrypted[16:]), 16)
```